# Download pdf document from Sharepoint library to local folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api

How to download Pdf from document library to local folder using rest api or jsom?
anyone has idea? help.

Comment: Plz check following link.It worked for me . http://www.techmikael.com/2013/07/how-to-copy-files-between-sites-using.html

Comment: It is between two libraries right. I need to download in a local folder without opening pdf to a new browser.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81685)

Comment: please refer link for above question. I had found a solution for it.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225086/download-document-from-sharepoint-library-to-local-machine